# Is this scala function to heavy/doing too many things to unit test properly?

Tags: scala, scalatest

OK, so I am looking at testing libraries, in particular ScalaTest & ScalaMock.

I wanted to write a test to test this function that I have written:

```
def gameMenuSelect(): State = {
  Try(UI.readOption) match {
    case Success(i) => {
      i match {
        case 1 => HumanGame
        case 2 => MachineGame
        case 3 => sys.exit(0)
        case _ =>
          UI.invalidSelectionMsg
          ChoosingGame
      }
    }
    case Failure(e) => UI.invalidSelectionMsg; ChoosingGame
  }

}
```

A bit of background, `UI.readOption` is a simple `scala.io.StdIn.readInt`.
`State` is a Trait - subsequently `HumanGame`, `MachineGame` and `ChoosingGame` are also Traits that extend `State`.

The problem is I have no idea how I would test it, the reason is because I feel like this function does too much.

It is reading input, validating that the input given is indeed a number/integer and not throwing a `NumberFormatException`. Given that the input is an integer it is match on allowable integers.

I really feel like there is a lot to test, also a lot that I am not sure is unit testable.

Could I have some opinions on whether you feel that this function is doing too many things, whether I should try to break up the reading of the integer and the matching of it?

Thanks.

Comment: This function does too much! as it's clearly not using Dependency Injection where you can mock the Try and force to cover Success and Failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, should absolutely try to separate the "side-effecting" bits, reading and writing, from the selection logic. The selection logic can return something like

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def selectGame(i: Int): GameError \/ State = 
  i match {
    case 1 => HumanGame.right
    case 2 => MachineGame.right
    case _ => InvalidGame(i).left
  }

sealed trait GameError
case class InvalidGame(i: Int) extends GameError

object GameError {
  def render(e: GameError): String =
    e match {
      case InvalidGame(i) => 
        s"Invalid game choice: $i. Only 1 and 2 are acceptable values"
    }
}
```

Note that I also model the error into a specific type instead of just using strings.

Then you can do the same with your number parsing:

```
def parseInt(i: String): ParseError \/ Int = 
  ???
```

For your "effects" you can use Scalaz `IO` for the interactions with the console:

```
def readLine: IO[String] = 
  IO(StdIn.readLine)

def printLine(line: String): IO[Unit] = 
  IO(println(line))
```

Then, with a bit more code, you can use the `EitherT[IO, E, A]` monad to "assemble" all your functions:

```
 // I will provide a full example if you want to go this way
 val actions: EitherT[IO, ApplicationError, Unit] = 
   for {
     line <- readLine
     i    <- parseInt(line)
     s    <- selectGame(i)  
     _    <- printLine(s.render)
   } yield ()
```

The `actions` value will both have `IO` side-effects and collect errors, stopping the process if there are any.

Eventually this all makes your testing a lot easier because you have isolated the "pure" parts which are way easier to test: no setup, no mocks, just pure functions.

Comment: Thanks Eric, this has been a huge input, originally the function did only take an integer and return a value, but I then lumped it into one thinking that it was a logical thing to do, but it made it more complicated, the ScalaZ things are incredibly useful as, not something I have used before, time to get experimenting!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are too many side effects in your function. Not only the reading of the integer, but also sys.exit(0). You could change the method to accept the integer as a parameter, and also add an EndingGame state that you could use for case 3. You would then have a pure function that is easily testable.